# Change content of <option> elements

Tags: jquery

I have a `select` widget with a couple of AJAX enhancements.

```
<select id="authors">
    <option value="1">Foo Bar</option>
    <option value="2" selected="selected">Bar Baz</option>
</select>
```

Now, if the selected option changes, I want to change the "content" ("Foo Bar" and "Bar Baz" in the example). How can I do that with jQuery? I tried the following, but obviously, it doesn't work.

```
$('#authors').change(function(){
    $('#authors option[selected=selected]').html('new content');
});
```

/edit: to clarify, the selector `'#authors option[selected=selected]'` works fine, it selects the correct `option` DOM element. But `.html('new content')` does nothing.

2nd edit: OK, this is embarrassing. I tried my code in Chrome's JavaScript console, where it didn't have any effect. After jAndy clearly demonstrated that it works in jsFiddle, I tried it in the FireBug console, and there it works. Lesson learned :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#authors').find('option:selected').html('new content');
```

example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/4yUqL/38/

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use text() instead of html() ?

Comment: The `$('#authors option[selected=selected]')` part works fine, it selects the correct DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#authors option:selected").html('new content');
```